# React.PureComponent question about documentation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) say

> If these contain complex data structures, it may produce
> **false-negatives** for deeper differences

By false negative does it mean when React will say that "do not re render" while it should?
If yes, can someone bring example why a complex data structure could result in such case?

Because if I have some prop say

```
item = 
{
  name:{
     details:{
          number:5
     }
  }
}
```

When I change `number` in *immutable* way, top level object should change too right, so why will it produce false negative?

Comment: I think they mean people often write buggy code with complex data structures and it’s a confusing line from their docs. The equality check is very straightforward (referentially) so it’s not like there are “edge cases” in complex data structures. It’s just that people often don’t update these structures “correctly” - i.e. they end up mutating things

Comment: @Adam Yeah the docs is confusing if people don't mutate things than that line doesn't make sense right ?

Comment: I made a library specially to solve this problem, check it out https://www.npmjs.com/package/@alentoma/usestate

Comment: @Alen.Toma I think you should improve the docs I could not understand purpose of your lib

Comment: I detest libraries (or frameworks) that do "magic" (MobX) that allow you to mutate things and have them be reactive. It teaches a bad pattern, no matter how much people may like them. You need to understand the "hows" and "whys" of immutability in order to understand reactivity. Reactivity, after all, is just a callback.